# Wpf xaml -IsExpanded true for only first element only

Tags: wpf, xaml, view, tree

How can I make it so that `Wpf xaml -IsExpanded` is always true for *just* the first element?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM, you can bind the `IsExpanded` to your `ViewModel`.

XAML like this:

```
<TreeView ItemSource={Binding Items}>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</TreeView>
```

In your `ViewModel`:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ...
  public bool IsExpanded
  {
    get
    {
      return _isExpanded;
    }
    set
    {
      if (value != _isExpanded)
      {
        _isExpanded = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Then you can set the IsExpanded property true of your first Data in Items while others false.

(Unfortunately I can't test at the moment, but I think that will help)